# What data type should an MVC model class use to back/represent a database column of type Image?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, image-processing, asp.net-mvc-4, types

In playing along with "Programming Razor," I've run into a conundrum. If I have a table with these columns:

```
ID      int
Title   nvarchar
Body    nText
Photo   Image
```

...how should the corresponding MVC Model class be declared? I have:

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public Byte[] FauxToe { get; set; }
}
```

...but the byte array for the image (probably will be jpg or png) is just a guess, at best.

Comment: I understand this is question about EF?

Comment: good point; I changed one of my tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be the perfect answer but I'm just trying to help. According to Programming Entity Framework DbContect by J.Lerman this should be used to store images...

```
[Column(TypeName = "image")]
public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
```

However, as it's code first, after the db was generated the type of the columns was... varbinary(MAX).

And this is from here other book Programing Entity Framework: Code first, where the schema was created.

> The parameter provided to the Column annotation is specific to the
>   database that you are mapping to. We want to store Photo in a SQL
>   Server image field. As long as it’s possible to coerce the type used
>   for the property to the database data type you specify (e.g., coerce a
>   byte[] to an image), you can configure the data type.

But as I said, it didn't map to image type, but to varbinary(MAX)

Regarding other fields, you are trying to map int to long with ID. Make sure your table is called properly or that you use Table attribute.